# Flutter on windows 11 + Visual Studio Code: ! Unknown upstream repository & No Device responses nothing on click

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I've tried installing Flutter according to https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk through `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable` command. However, after executing command `flutter doctor -v`, I got following output:

```
C:\Users\yi>flutter doctor
Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ...
Expanding downloaded archive...
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Downloading Material fonts...                                      837ms
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                      578ms
Downloading package sky_engine...                                  569ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                           951ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                   972ms
Downloading windows-x64 tools...                                    4.9s
Downloading windows-x64/font-subset tools...                       732ms
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel @upstream, 3.7.10, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413], locale zh-CN)
    ! Unknown upstream repository.
      Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.77.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I suppose this issue is not something important and I tried creating a new Flutter project in my `Visual Studio Code` from `Flutter: New Project` as following:

[image]

Then I tried opening this project in `Visual Studio Code`. When I clicked `No Device` status bar I got nothing. Here nothing means no popup, no dropdown menu, just nothing happended as I've never clicked on it.

When I tried debugging my project, there was also nothing happended.

What's wrong with my flutter environment? Should I digged into the `Flutter` extension to get more information?

---

[2023.04.08] Debugging from extension shows `daemon.getSupportedPlatforms` response nothing.

[image]